# How to create an account in any other program using CPI in which PDA is used as signer and payer

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda, account, cpi

I just want to invoke initialize method of callee program from caller program in which pda account should be signer.

**Callee Program**

```
#[program]
mod callee {
    use super::*;

    // I want to call this method using cpi in which pda should be signer.
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.new_account.data = data;
        msg!("Changed data to: {}!", data);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    data: u64
}
```

**Caller Program**

```
#[constant]
const USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS: &[u8] = b"USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS";

#[program]
pub mod caller {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_user_account(ctx: Context<CreateUserAccount>) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.user_account.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("user_account").unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn invoke_transaction<'info>(
        ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, InvokeTransaction<'info>>,
        data: Vec<u8>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // Am i doing any mistake here
        let ix = solana_program::instruction::Instruction {
            program_id: ctx.accounts.program_to_be_called.key(),
            accounts: vec![
                AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.new_account.key(), true),
                AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.user_account.key(), true),
                AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.system_program.key(), false),
            ],
            data,
        };

        solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
            &ix,
            &[
                ctx.accounts.new_account.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.user_account.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ],
            &[&[
                USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS,
                ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref(),
                &[ctx.accounts.user_account.bump],
            ]],
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateUserAccount<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer=signer,
        space= 8 + std::mem::size_of::<UserAccount>(),
        seeds=[USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS,signer.key().as_ref()],
    bump)]
    pub user_account: Account<'info, UserAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct UserAccount {
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub bump: u8,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InvokeTransaction<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_account: Account<'info, UserAccount>,

    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    pub program_to_be_called: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub new_account: AccountInfo<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

- **Error i am getting** Invalid program argument.
- **Note:-** When i use signer of invoke_transaction as a signer in cpi this code works fine, but when i use user_account (pda) as a signer i gets above given error.

**How i have solved this issue**

- As 0xShuk have mentioned that we can fix this issue by creating system program owned pda, i have initially tried to create system owned pda account by transferring sol from phantom wallet to my pda address but when i was trying this phantom was not allowing me to do this and it was throwing error as "Invalid address".
- After this i have tried to create system owned pda account by using `solana_program::system_instruction::create_account` method but it was still not working, but by this way i was able to create system program owned account.
- **Solution:-** Then i have created system program owned pda by just transferring sol using solana program, you can do this by using `solana_sdk` or `web3js Solana`.

```
pub fn create_system_program_owned_pda(ctx: Context<CreatePDA>) -> Result<()> {
        let lamports = 1000000;
        let (_pubkey, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
            &[USER_TEMP_ACCOUNT, ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref()],
            &ID,
        );
        anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
            &anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
                &ctx.accounts.signer.key(),
                &ctx.accounts.temp_account.key(),
                lamports,
            ),
            &[
                ctx.accounts.temp_account.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
            ],
            &[&[
                USER_TEMP_ACCOUNT,
                ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref(),
                &[bump],
            ]],
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreatePDA<'info> {
    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    #[account(mut)]
    pub temp_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Hope this will help you and eventually thank you so much 0xShuk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `user_account` in your caller program. You are invoking the callee program with `user_account` as the signer which means that this account will pay the rent exemption fee for `new_account`. But since `user_account` is owned by the caller program, it can't be used to pay the rent fees, hence, it can't act as a signer.

The solution is to use different seeds for signing the CPI and for `user_account`. Your caller program should be like this:

```
[constant]
const USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS: &[u8] = b"USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS";
const CPI_SEEDS: &[u8] = b"CPI_SEEDS";

#[program]
pub mod caller {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_user_account(ctx: Context<CreateUserAccount>) -> Result<()> {
        let (_authority, cpi_bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
            &[CPI_SEEDS, ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref()], &ID
        );

        ctx.accounts.user_account.bump = cpi_bump;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn invoke_transaction<'info>(
        ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, InvokeTransaction<'info>>,
        data: Vec<u8>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // Am i doing any mistake here
        let ix = solana_program::instruction::Instruction {
            program_id: ctx.accounts.program_to_be_called.key(),
            accounts: vec![
                AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.new_account.key(), true),
                AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.cpi_authority.key(), true),
                AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.system_program.key(), false),
            ],
            data,
        };

        solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
            &ix,
            &[
                ctx.accounts.new_account.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.cpi_authority.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ],
            &[&[
                CPI_SEEDS,
                ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref(),
                &[ctx.accounts.user_account.bump],
            ]],
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateUserAccount<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer=signer,
        space= 8 + std::mem::size_of::<UserAccount>(),
        seeds=[USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS,signer.key().as_ref()],
    bump)]
    pub user_account: Account<'info, UserAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct UserAccount {
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub bump: u8,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InvokeTransaction<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_account: Account<'info, UserAccount>,

    /// CHECK: CPI Authority
    #[account(mut,
        seeds=[CPI_SEEDS,signer.key().as_ref()],
        bump = user_account.bump
    )]
    pub cpi_authority: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    pub program_to_be_called: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub new_account: AccountInfo<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Make sure to transfer some SOL to `cpi_authority` account before calling `invoke_transaction`, else your will get `0x1` error.

Comment: It means a pda Account cannot be used as rent payer, I have already tried same solution given by you but problem here is that in this case cpi_authority will be signer.

Comment: As you said that pda cannot be used as rent payer, can you please share any reference of it or article so I can get more information about it.

Comment: I didn't say that PDA can't be a rent payer. The pda can pay rent as demonstrated above. But the account paying rent must owned by `System` program. In your case, `user_account` is owned by the caller program when you initialised it in `create_user_account` instruction. So it no longer eligible to interact with `System` program to create account. That's why we used a different pda which isn't initialised yet and will be considered as `System` account once funded.

Comment: Ok will do research on it, but it would be great if you share some resources using which i can achieve this and it will be also helpful for other devs.

Comment: Hello 0xShuk, I have tried your suggested solution in which I am using system owned pda but it's still not working, it would be great if you help me to resolve it.

Comment: The code works, I've tested it. There must be some other specific issue with your code. Come in this chat room and post your issue: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145727/pda-signer. It would be easier to follow.

Comment: Hello 0xShuk, I don't have sufficient reputation on stack exchange so i cannot post on chat room.

Comment: You can post your solution in this post or there is a similar post like my issue you can also look it and provide solution of it https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6529/error-processing-instruction-0-invalid-program-argument-while-invoking-method

Comment: This https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6529/error-processing-instruction-0-invalid-program-argument-while-invoking-method post is much similar to my issue and this guy is trying to achieve same thing like me, can you please check it's code and resolve it ?

Comment: Hello 0xShuk, I have resolved issue by creating system owned pda by just transferring sol from program, earlier i was trying to do this by transferring sol from phantom wallet but phantom wallet was not allowing.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance and time.

Comment: Yes, Phantom has a protection against sending SOL to unfunded off-curve addresses. You can use other wallets like Backpack, those won't give the same error.