# "Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument" while invoking method of other program using cpi

Tags: anchor, pda, account, cpi

***The callee program***

```
#[program]
pub mod puppet {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(_ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn set_data(ctx: Context<SetData>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let puppet = &mut ctx.accounts.puppet;
        puppet.data = data;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub puppet: Account<'info, Data>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SetData<'info> {
    #[account(mut,signer)]
    pub puppet: Account<'info, Data>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Data {
    pub data: u64,
}
```

***The caller program***

```
#[constant]
const USER_TEMP_ACCOUNT: &[u8] = b"USER_TEMP_ACCOUNT";

#[program]
mod puppet_master {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_user_temp_account(ctx: Context<CreateUserTempAccount>) -> Result<()> {
        let (pubkey, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
            &[USER_TEMP_ACCOUNT, ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref()],
            &ID,
        );
        anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
            &anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(
                &ctx.accounts.signer.key(),
                &pubkey,
                100000000,
                50,
                &anchor_lang::system_program::ID,
            ),
            &[
                ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.user_account.to_account_info(),
            ],
            &[&[
                USER_TEMP_ACCOUNT,
                ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref(),
                &[bump],
            ]],
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn pull_strings(ctx: Context<PullStrings>, _data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.puppet_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_accounts = Initialize {
            puppet: ctx.accounts.puppet.to_account_info(),
            user: ctx.accounts.user_account.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        };
        let (_pubkey, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
            &[USER_TEMP_ACCOUNT, ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref()],
            &ID,
        );
        puppet::cpi::initialize(CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            cpi_program,
            cpi_accounts,
            &[&[
                USER_TEMP_ACCOUNT,
                ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref(),
                &[bump],
            ]],
        ))
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct PullStrings<'info> {
    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub puppet: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub puppet_program: Program<'info, Puppet>,
    // #[account(mut)]
    // pub user_account: Account<'info, UserAccount>,
    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateUserTempAccount<'info> {
    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct UserAccount {}
```

- I am just trying to invoke `initialize` method of `puppet` program from `puppet_master` program in which pda is signer and payer.
- As explained [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/688/anchor-initialize-account-with-pda-as-payer), i am using system owned PDA as a signer and payer to invoke `initialize` method of `puppet` program.
- When i am invoking `pull_string` method of `puppet_master` program to invoke `initialize` method of `puppet` program in which actual transaction signer is signer and payer it's working fine.
- But when i am using system owned pda as a signer and payer i am getting error as "Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below given code to create system program owned pda account.

```
    pub fn create_user_temp_account(ctx: Context<CreateUserTempAccount>) -> Result<()> {
        let (pubkey, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
            &[USER_TEMP_ACCOUNT, ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref()],
            &ID,
        );
        let lamports = 1000000000;
        anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
            &anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
                &ctx.accounts.signer.key(),
                &ctx.accounts.user_account.key(),
                lamports,
            ),
            &[
                ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.user_account.to_account_info(),
            ],
            &[&[
                USER_TEMP_ACCOUNT,
                ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref(),
                &[bump],
            ]],
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }
```

You can check this post [How to create an account in any other program using CPI in which PDA is used as signer and payer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/how-to-create-an-account-in-any-other-program-using-cpi-in-which-pda-is-used-as)